# Remove missing Images from array React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-image

I have array of images coming from external API, I want to filter images which are broken before showing them on carousel. as you can see now I map every image and showing MissingImage component as unloader if image is missing, but in my situation sometimes there are more than half images not available on API. how can I skip images if they aren't available before passing them to Carousel component?

```
          {images.map((img, i) => (
        <Dot
          key={i}
          type="button"
          onClick={() => {
            setThumbsPosition(i);
            goToSlide(i);
            setActiveSlide(i);
          }}
          active={activeSlide === i}
          ref={i === 0 && slideRef}
        >
          <SliderDotImage>
            <Img
              loading="lazy"
              src={[img.url.bigger]}
              unloader={<MissingImage small />}
            />
          </SliderDotImage>
        </Dot>
      ))}
```

Comment: you'd have to fetch them all first

Comment: @evolutionxbox I can't because of the CORS policy...

Comment: Then I’m not sure you can know before putting them on the page

Answer (score 0):

You can use && operator to check whether we have an image URL or not:

```
{images.map((img, i) => (
        <Dot
          key={i}
          type="button"
          onClick={() => {
            setThumbsPosition(i);
            goToSlide(i);
            setActiveSlide(i);
          }}
          active={activeSlide === i}
          ref={i === 0 && slideRef}
        >
          <SliderDotImage>
            <Img
              loading="lazy"
              src={img?.url && img.url} // or src={img && img.url}
              unloader={<MissingImage small />}
            />
          </SliderDotImage>
        </Dot>
      ))}
```

Comment: Image URL is always available, but  problem is that on that URL sometimes there are no image at all